# Trigger Rule with Filefield 'when field has changed'

Tags: 7, rules, files

This problem has been giving me a headache for four days now, so I thought it'd be best to see if somebody knows of a better answer than me :)

I've got a set of different rules that check if various field types have been updated 'after updating existing content'. The problem is that each one works fine, except for the only filefield type which will not work. The condition used is a 'NOT Data comparison' on the field checking the 'node-unchanged' version against the new 'node' version. This works with every other type of field and actions appropriately (that I have used at least), just not the filefield type; the rule just fires regardless of changes or not on the filefield.

I also found this post about a very similar problem: https://www.drupal.org/node/1011014#comment-10040082

I think I have the makings of a workaround, but I just wanted to check this with some fellow developers first as my PHP isn't the best.

If I were to enable the PHP module then add a condition in rules that checks the 'source' attribute to see if a new file has been added... would this work? The code I have is:

```
if (isset($object->field_FILEFIELD_NAME[0]['source'])) {
  //Check for new files
}
```

I believe that $object is the node passed on by rule function as argument.

Is this a good idea/best approach? Any ideas or workarounds would be great as I'm stumped :(

Thanks guys!